# File Possibly Corrupted

Tags: file-corruption

I have a question on another stackexchange site and it was mentioned that my file might be corrupt. Is there a way to verify this? I have access to mac/windows and the file will not open on either machine.

Here is the original question:

https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/7110/video-file-format-wont-play

Comment: Please don't post your question on [multiple sites](http://serverfault.com/questions/477764/file-possibly-corrupted). Cross-posting is considered abusive behavior.

Comment: The question started out as a video question and now it is a corrupt file question.

Comment: I'm referring to the exact same question you posted on Server Fault just a minute earlier than this one.

Answer (score 1):

Grab the MD5 or SHA512 (or any other hash function) hash from both files (if you still have the working/source file) and compare them.

If they are both identical, the file is not corrupt.

Comment: I do not have a working version.

Comment: I've downloaded your file (other topic) and there are some 'video repair tools'. I've managed to get [something](http://gerwim.nl/s/cvDmO0.png) out of it.

Comment: what tools are you using.  That is definitely the video.  I picked a small one because obviously I was sharing it.  I have many more just like this file unfortunately.

Comment: @KyleRogers I've used [this link](http://mp4repair.org/pwt6/preview.html) - however there are many more.

Comment: @KyleRogers - You already were told how to resolve this: http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/7110/video-file-format-wont-play